# How can I change character class date variables to POSIXlt class when there are multiple date formats?

Tags: r, date, datetime, lubridate

I'm struggling with converting character class dates of many different format types (e.g., yyyy/mm/dd; mm/dd/yyyy; yyyy-mm-dd; mm-dd-yyyy; yy-mm-dd; mm-dd-yy; etc.) to POSIXlt class. Ideally, I would like to convert all birth_dates to POSIXlt class with yyyy/mm/dd format (see sample data below). Is there any simple way to do this in R?:

```
   id  birth_date  start_date  age
  102   08/09/1993  2013/09/01 20
  103   1995-02-21  2013/09/01 18
  104   01-15-94    2013/09/01 19
  105   88-12-30    2013/09/01 24
```

Here is what I have been doing thus far. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work (I wind up with more NAs than there should be) given all of the different ways in which the original date is formatted:

```
  library(lubridate)
  data$birth_date1<-as.Date(data$birth_date,format="%Y-%m-%d") #Convert character class to date class
  data$birth_date2<-ymd(swc3$birth_date1) #Convert date class to POSIXlt class using lubridate pkg
```

Comment: What are you going to do with ambiguous dates (ie "01-02-03")? It's impossible for a human to know what the right answer is.

Comment: You can use `parse_date_time` from `lubridate`

Comment: I feel like this is a data-cleaning problem and less a programming one. The solution is probably going to involve some ugly regex and temporary columns.

Answer (score 1):

That's horrible. Could be worse though. At least there are delimiters in there, like "-" and "/".

#### Short Answer

Yes, there's an easy way to parse that in R. Apply `parse_date_time()` separately to each birth date, giving it a decent `orders` list to chose from, and carefully set the order of the guesses. You'll need to convert the "integer-time" to a useful time when you're done.

See the Long Answer for details.

#### Long Answer

This is why the `lubridate` package has `parse_date_time()`. But there are problems. Let's see:

```
require(lubridate)
# WRONG! doesn't work as intended.
as.Date(
    parse_date_time(data$birth_date, 
                    orders=c("ymd", "mdy", "mdY", "Ymd")
    )
)
```

> ```
>  [1] "1993-08-09" "1995-02-21" "1994-01-15" "0088-12-30"
> ```

That looks great, except for the last one. What's going on?

`parse_date_time()` is selecting a "best fit" set of orders and formats to use when parsing the dates, and the last element is the odd one out.

To make this work as intended, you'll need to apply `parse_date_time()` one-by-one to each date, because each date format was apparently selected more-or-less at random. This will be slower, but it will give more useful answers.

```
# RIGHT. Some conversion of results required.
parsed <- sapply(data[,"birth_date"],
                 parse_date_time,
                 orders=c("ymd", "mdy", "mdY", "Ymd") )
parsed
```

> ```
> 08/09/1993 1995-02-21   01-15-94   88-12-30 
> 744854400  793324800  758592000  599443200
> ```

Ok, those look like Unix-time integers, which are the `unclass()`'d version of what `parse_date_time()` produces. And none are negative, so they must all have happened after 1970. This is encouraging. Convert:

```
# Conversion of results
parsed <- as.POSIXct(parsed, origin="1970-01-01", tz = "GMT")
as.Date(parsed)
```

> ```
> 08/09/1993   1995-02-21     01-15-94     88-12-30 
> "1993-08-09" "1995-02-21" "1994-01-15" "1988-12-30"
> ```

`lubridate` and `parse_date_time()` are very good at what they do.

Since you asked for POSIXlt, not Date types:

```
as.POSIXlt(parsed)
```

> ```
>                 08/09/1993                 1995-02-21 
> "1993-08-09 10:00:00 AEST" "1995-02-21 11:00:00 AEDT" 
>                  01-15-94                   88-12-30 
> "1994-01-15 11:00:00 AEDT" "1988-12-30 11:00:00 AEDT"
> ```

Though I personally prefer only having dates when the actual time isn't important; these are assumed to be all happening at midnight UTC, and are converted to my time zone (Eastern Australia).